# Hotel booking—number of rooms booked between dates, by day

Tags: excel-formula

Is there a way I can put in a formula that will auto fill-in by columns (starting with column D) the dates between two dates? And add columns.  I.e., see below—(for hotel booking room pickup)

```
     A                B               C          D    E    F    G   H    I 
Arrival Date  Departure Date  No Days Booked    7/2  7/3  7/4  7/5  7/6 7/7
2.  07/02/2015      07/05/2015      =B2-A2 (3)   x    x     x    
3.  07/03/2015      07/06/2015      =B3-A3 (3)        x     x   x    
4.  07/04/2015      07/07/2015      =B4-A4 (3)              x   x    x

TOTAL Nights by day                     9        1    2     3   2    1
```

(PS  I'm a neebie with no VB experience, just trying to help out an organization that has a once per year event that books over 300 rooms)
Thanks for any hints.
Marie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in D2, enter this: `=IF(AND(D$1>=$A2,D$1<$B2),"x","")`.  Then drag over and down.

Here's what I get:

[image]

(Note: For `D1:I1` I entered the values as `7/2`, `7/3`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks so much "BruceWayne".  I decided to replace the "x" with the number 1 so the columns will add and I could do a pivot table because the bookings need to be sorted by Regions of the World.  Took me a while to figure out how to get the 1 to be a number, but finally realized just needed to get rid of the "" around it.  So glad I found this website and that there are some out there willing to help others.

Comment: @Marie - glad to hear! Welcome to SO. You can mark it as the "answer" by clicking the check mark.  You asked a good question (stated your problem/issue, what your data looks like, and what you expected out of it) - which helps us help you!