# Number of rooms booked by day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I found a post about this question in 2015 and I am not able to make that formula work. Is it a matter of Excel having updated formula options? Even when I copy exactly what the post from 2015 shows the formula is not working. I appreciate any suggestions. :-)

[Hotel booking—number of rooms booked between dates, by day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448484/hotel-booking-number-of-rooms-booked-between-dates-by-day)

Comment: What is not working?  please explain what it is doing that is in error.

Comment: If I took out the link then the question makes no sense. Please put all of the details in the question and only link as supporting evidence.

Comment: Also, the formula used is bog standard. It hasn't changed. You're implementing it wrongly. We can't see that unless you post your details of what you're doing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I will add additional detail shortly to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The date in the column headers and the rows need to be the same year to work. If you just put the column headers as month/day, then it automatically assumes it to be the current year. Which means you would see nothing work since the examples are in 2015. Put this in D2 then drag left and then drag down.

> =IF(AND(D$1<=$B2,D$1>$A2),1,"")

[image: Current Excel file]

Comment: There is nothing in the question that supports your answer that the OP is getting year wrong.

Comment: If OP is just copying and pasting, then excel will interpret 7/2 as 7/2/2022 which will not be within 7/2/2015 - 7/5/2015. I had to assetively write 7/2/2022 to have it work. So OP saying "when I copy exactly what the post from 2015 shows", that lends me to think that they're getting the year wrong.

Comment: That's an assumption I would have checked with the OP before posting.

Comment: Different strokes for different folks. If this works for OP, they can accept as the answer. If not, no harm.

Comment: This site is about quality questions and quality answers for ***future*** readers, and not necessarily the OP. The question is extremely average and vague. Your answer is really a guess. As this stands this question and answer are a waste of time for future readers. There's not no harm.